# Enabling HTTPS on Linux EC2 Instance using Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I am trying to enable https on a Linux ec2 instance. I am struggling to figure out which port to expose and the DNS is not resolving. Here is my Dockerfile [image] I have tried to create a load balancer listening on port 80 through an ALB and then used the DNS of the LB to route to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) through a CNAME. It still will not resolve. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to have attached a PNG file instead of your Dockerfile; can you replace that with the actual text of the Dockerfile, and any other steps that are required to reproduce the issue?  The DNS resolution will be about your Route 53 configuration, and won't really have anything to do with your application code; there are a couple of places it's possible to do TLS termination.  This doesn't necessarily sound like a programming problem.

Comment: The PNG file is a picture of my Dockerfile and I never said this was a programming issue. It's a question of how to configure https using docker and ec2\

Comment: I would say a lot of information is missing here. You haven't provided any information on *how* you are running the container. You haven't provided information about the Security Group you are using for the EC2 instance. Additionally, to fully utilize something like HTTPS, you would have to provide a valid TLS certificate.

Comment: yes, sorry about that. So I am using the container on an ec2 instance just doing a simple ``` docker build && docker run``` the container runs and works fine when using normal http. My security groups for both the ALB and the ec2 are OPEN fully for testing purposes and my certs is coming from  ACM in AWS.